# How do I create a Download button in HTML?

Tags: html, button, download

Hello I am trying to code an HTML button to download an image.

Here is the code I am using that seems like I am getting close but not quite there.

```
<a href="https://assets.giftcardsuite.com/valentinesday/Valentines-Day-Theme-1.png" download>
  <img src="https://assets.giftcardsuite.com/valentinesday/Valentines-Day-Theme-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="happy-valentines-day"> Click Here To Download
</a>
```

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like when I download it:
https://snag.gy/tTC2ER.jpg

Comment: Why are you not using the `<button>` tag if you want a button? Anyways here you have what you [need](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_download_button.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check this response: [href image link download on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408146/href-image-link-download-on-click)
2. Also this answer using [Jquery Download Plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)
3. Try [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50042812/10849656):

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/50042812/10849656

function forceDownload(link){
    var url = link.getAttribute("data-href");
    var fileName = link.getAttribute("download");
    link.innerText = "...";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
        var tag = document.createElement('a');
        tag.href = imageUrl;
        tag.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(tag);
        tag.click();
        document.body.removeChild(tag);
        link.innerText="Download";
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-href='https://i.imgur.com/mdYoHMD.jpg' download="Image.jpg" onclick='forceDownload(this)'>Download Image</a>
```

Comment: Thank you I tried implementing your code:  <a download="https://assets.giftcardsuite.com/valentinesday/Valentines-Day-Theme-1.png" href="https://assets.giftcardsuite.com/valentinesday/Valentines-Day-Theme-1.png" title="ImageName">
  <img alt="ImageName" src="https://assets.giftcardsuite.com/valentinesday/Valentines-Day-Theme-1.png">
</a>   It doesn't seem to work. Do you know what I may be doing incorrectly?

Comment: @Giftcardsuite the answer was updated with a script that forces the download.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is disarranged

Try this:

```
<a href="https://assets.giftcardsuite.com/valentinesday/Valentines-Day-Theme-1.png" download>Click here</a> to download
```

Answer (score 0):

When I download something I usually use my download function below. I don't need to remove from DOM because it never gets placed in the DOM.

**Javascript**

```
function download(data, name) {
      var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octect-stream'});
      var bloburl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = bloburl;
      a.download = name;
      a.click();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
}
```